# Vim setup for Python 3

Tags: vimrc, ide

I want to turn VIM into my Python 3 development environment. What is the best .vimrc configuration and what are good Plug-ins for the job?

Comment: The best vimrc really depends on the user, I think you should drive your question towards specific configuration points (navigation, search, plugins) instead of searching for the "best vimrc".
(also because mine is the best ;) )

Comment: also worth reading: https://www.fullstackpython.com/vim.html

Comment: check out these as well: https://realpython.com/blog/python/vim-and-python-a-match-made-in-heaven/ and https://github.com/klen/python-mode

Comment: Also, instead of looking for python, I would really recommend trying doing with "raw" vim and incrementing as your need comes. I think it's worth trying and adding bits of config now and then. But if you search for the "best" config, I would say: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Configuring+PyCharm+to+work+as+a+Vim+editor

Comment: You can see my `.vimrc` here: https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/dotFiles/blob/master/.vimrc They're not all set with python in mind, but IMO they're reasonable and useful starting settings.

Comment: For one thing, I’d recommend using neovim instead of vim. It’s a drop in replacement with async functionality and built in terminal. Aside from that, it can process files with several thousands of lines, while vim would struggle at that